# Reactjs Redux applymiddleware not calling?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux for the first time and I'm getting this error on the redux devtools:

error: "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

This is my store.js code:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {productListReducer} from './reducers/productReducers';

const initialState = {};
const reducer = combineReducers ( {
    productList: productListReducer,
})

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))); 

export default store;
```

And the productReducers.js where I have the switch for `PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL`:

```
import { PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL } from "../constants/productConstants";

function productListReducer(state = {products:[]}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return {loading: true};

        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {loading: false, products: action.payload}; 

        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return {loading: false, error: action.payload};

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export {productListReducer};
```

The import from the last code comes from here (productConstants.js):

```
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL';
```

productActions.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  } from '../constants/productConstants';

const listProducts = () => async(dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST);
        const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products");
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data});
    }
    catch(error) {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message});
    }
} 

export {listProducts}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you edit your question to include the code for ``PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL`` action and the code where you are dispatching it? Also, in the future please don't post images of error messages. Just copy them into the question as text.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the advice, It is my first post here.

As you asked I edited and I hope it's enought information so you can help me!

Again, thanks for the attention!

Comment: Closer, but you also need to include the code for the action creator (the function you pass to ``dispatch`` to initiate the action). That's likely where your problem is.

Comment: Sure. Sorry for the lack of knowledge, I'm kinda new to web dev. And this is my first project by my own. I added the productActions.js on the question! Thank you for the patience!

Answer (score 0):

guys.

My bad, I was writing `dispatch(PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST);` instead of `dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST});` inside the try-catch in productActions.js, that's why the `PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST` was assumed as a string and not an object...

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Good luck.